# "Price per item" -- Paypal possible modification?

Tags: paypal

I am enclosing a screenshot of an example Paypal button flow to this page ...

I was wondering if it is possible to modify "Price per item" to something that's more descriptive? For example, "Monthly School Fees", etc?

Thank you for your help!

[image]